# flash slider unresponsive

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, slider

I have a flash movie playing some music, but the slider controlling the volume has become unresponsive. I have no idea why. Can someone help me. msg me if you want the see the actionscript.

Comment: Not sure how you want people to message you. If you place the piece of actionscript code that has the slider then other people can help you as well as learn from it.

Comment: i did not post my actionscript because it is 7 kinda long files and i had no idea where to localize my problem.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem. I was careless with layering my movieclips. If anyone get this problem, check if there is an empty movie clip on top of the clip containing the components. You can fix this by switching the addChild() commands, or use addChildAt()